# Salty flavor in beer?

Tags: additives, flavor

Recently, I've noticed a slight salty taste in a few beers. It's generally toward the end of the glass, and it's generally when I'm dehydrated. It's happened with Long Trail Ale and Stone Arrogant Bastard, both in the past two weeks.

So, I guess this is a multiple choice question:

A) The beer actually has salty flavoring, and I don't taste it until the beer is a bit warmer.

B) My friends are dicks and threw salt in my beer when I went to the bathroom.

C) I'm super dehydrated.

Comment: not B. definitely not B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't noticed a salty flavor in either of those two beers before (or, except for a few rarities, in beer in general). Also, you're the only one who can answer C for us, how dehydrated are you? Why not just get some Gatorade? Why not make Gatorale with electrolytes, fruit flavor, and a shit ton of hops? Actually, don't do that. Patent pending on that idea.

I vote for the friends are dicks idea. The real insidiousness of this plan is that instead of just messing up a few beers for you they're making you question this saltiness outside of drinking hours.

Gatorale - Is it in you?...Not for long.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are salt ions in all beers.  It is possible that as your palatte fatigues you are just more sensitive to it.

There are, however, other flavors in beer that could be interpreted as salty, but are something else.  Particularly the hop profiles of the beers, perhaps.

The good news is that you need more experimentation.
Today: Drink 4 glasses of water during the day, then drink 4 long trails at night and see if they seem salty.
Tomorrow: Don't drink the water, wear four sweaters and walk around the house a lot.  Then drink the 4 long trails at night and report back.

Comment: I think this sounds like a good experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect option B) as the likely explanation.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to bring the funny to this answer. Then I will upvote.

Comment: I tried to come up with something funny or a way to replicate it. Brain hadn't started.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible your water has become saltier, and is leaving a residue in the glass!

Comment: This "phenomenon" has occurred at two different bars in two different time zones.